# Difference between clear terminal and kill terminal in VS Code?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, terminal, kill

I am coding on an M2 Macbook Air, and when right clicking on the termial in VS Code, I see 2 commands: `kill terminal` and `clear`. What is the difference between both? They seem fairly similar.

Answer (score 0):

Killing the terminal stops whatever is running from running and shuts down the terminal; clearing the terminal removes previous commands to "tidy up" the appearance, but keeps the terminal open.

Comment: when i kill the terminal, the terminal window is still open

Comment: Ah that's odd! It does on my Macbook Pro

Answer (score 0):

... one clears it ("clears the screen" without closing the session- more of a visual aesthetic thing to visually declutter). Somewhat related but not 100% related: the [UNIX `clear` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clear_(Unix)), and [readline's `clear-display` binding](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/readline-common/readline.3readline.en.html#clear).

and one kills it (terminates the shell session). Somewhat related but not 100% related: the `logout` command and [readline's `end-of-file` binding](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/readline-common/readline.3readline.en.html#end%7E3) (since it's often configured to close upon the end-of-file character (see also `stty eof`)), bash's `exit` builtin command.

Also note that if you want to do these actions via VS Code's command palette, you can use `Terminal: Clear` and `Terminal: Kill the Active Terminal Instance` or the other `Terminal: Kill ...` commands.

Comment: Would the terminal window in VS Code close/hide if it is the only terminal window open if I `kill terminal`?

Comment: yep. that's what I (tried to) communicate in my post. If you find the wording of my post confusing, you can suggest an edit.

Comment: oh, its just that when there is only one terminal window open, it does not go away when I `kill terminal`

Comment: Interesting. It does on my machine. maybe it's a setting. I'll remove that part from my answer for now.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue. It must have been a bug on my end.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).